# Why is Data deleted upon getting it back from View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Database where I save Users and Roles, with a many-to-many Relationship. I have those imported via EF Database first as Models. When I try to add, update or remove Roles from a Person, nothing happens, or for example if I press on add, the last Role doesnt show up anymore.
After debugging it a bit. I found out, that after the View gives back the Model (Person) the Roles list is suddenly empty. Why is this and how can I fix it?

This is my Controller Methode to Edit a Person

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("BadRequest", "Error", new { area = "" });
            }

            Person person = await db.Person.FindAsync(id);

            if (person == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("NotFound", "Error", new { area = "" });
            }
            ViewBag.allRoles = db.Roles.ToList();
            return View(person);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "id,nachname,vorname,winLogon")] Person person, string command, int? roleId)
        {
            Role none = new Role { id = -1, name = "None" };
            var allRoles = db.Roles.ToList();
         
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (command != null && command == "remove")
                {
                    person.Roles.Remove(db.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == roleId));
                    return View(person);
                }

                if (command != null && command == "add")
                {
                    person.Roles.Add(none);
                    return View(person);
                }

                if (command != null && command == "save")
                {
                    person.Roles.Remove(none);
                    db.Entry(userRoles.User).State = EntityState.Modified;

                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            return View(person);
        }
```

This is the Person Model

```cs
public partial class Person
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Person()
    {
        this.Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }
    
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string nachname {get;set;}
    public string vorname {get;set;}
    public string winLogon {get;set;}

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles {get;set;}
}
```

And this is the Role Model

```cs
public partial class Rolle
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Rolle()
        {
            this.Person = new HashSet<Person>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Person> Person { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is the View

```html
@model Models.Person
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    List<Role> allRoles = ViewBag.allRoles;
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "People", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Person</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nachname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nachname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nachname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
 
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.vorname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.vorname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.vorname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.winLogon, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.winLogon, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.winLogon, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Roles; i++)
            {
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Roles, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Roles, new SelectList(allRoles, "id", "name", role), new { @class = "form-control-static col-md-1" })
                    <input type="hidden" name="roleId" value="@role.id" />
                    <input name="command" type="submit" value="remove" class="btn btn-default col-md-offset-1" />
                </div>
            }

            <input name="command" type="submit" value="add" class="btn btn-default col-md-offset-1" />
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input name="command" type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

 
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: The roles property **will** be empty as you're not posting back a full list of roles, and the person object generated by the model binding is not attached to your database context. You could try adding this at the start of your controller method to attach the person entity and then explicitly load the related entities: `_db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified; db.Entry(person).Collection(r => r.Roles).Load();`

Comment: That helped out a bit. Now Roles are not getting deleted upon trying to add a new one. The Problem now is 1. the roles still dont save, meaning if I press on remove after a Role and then Save the Roles does not get removed (same for adding), for that I would need to know how to add to the db.Entry(person).Collection I think. 2. The Roles selected in the DropDownList are not retrievable.

Comment: You're only calling `db.SaveChangesAsync()` when the command is "save"

Comment: But wouldnt db.SaveChangesAsync() save all changes to the database, like my SQL Database? Because then I possibly would have Users with the None role and so on